# Cryptic Psycopg2 error message

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am using Psycopg2 with PostgreSQL 8.4. While reading from a huge table, I suddenly get this cryptic error at the following line of code, after this same line of code has successfully fetched a few hundred thousand rows.

`somerows = cursorToFetchData.fetchmany(30000)`

psycopg2.DataError: invalid value "LÃ" for "DD"

DETAIL:  Value must be an integer.

My problem is that I have no column named "DD", and about 300 columns in that table (I know 300 columns is a design flaw). I would appreciate a hint about the meaning of this error message, or how to figure out where the problem lies. I do not understand how Psycop2 can have any requirements about the datatype while fetching rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you paste in the data from the row that's causing the problem? At a guess I'd say it's a badly formatted date entry, but hard to say.

(Can't comment, so has to be in a answer...)

Comment: From now on you can comment. ;) I will do this and see what it comes up with. I might remove the acceptance of the answer if a better one shows up.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a psycopg error, it is a postgres error.

After the error is raised, take a look at cur.query to see the query generated. Copy and paste it into psql and you'll see the same error. Then debug it from there.